# Images won't show on Heroku App after deploying Node JS, reading as text/html

Tags: node.js, image, heroku, deployment, static

I can't seem to get my images to load after deploying to heroku.  I've checked the JPG vs. jpg - they are all lowercase.  And my static file 'public' is being served because the CSS is working, but it looks like it's not reading the 'images' folder.

Everything is working locally.  What am I doing wrong ?!

Here's the [github repository](https://github.com/saraheymann/portfolio) that I'm working with.

Comment: Have you inspected the full HTTP response to your assets in network tab in Chrome's inspector? I suspect in addition to getting text/html you're also getting a response body that describes an error occurred. You're probably pointing `static` to the wrong folder. I personally have never used `process.cwd()` like you have on line 21 of server.js, bur rather something like `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));`.

Comment: Hi Charlie- thanks for the response.  I tried that code as well and same result.  The other things (like the CSS) from the folder are working- and everything works before I deploy to Heroku.  I'll check tomorrow and see if there are any additional errors

Comment: Cool. Can you drop a URL to the Heroku app? I understand if not. May help diagnose this. I've been in the same boat before.

Comment: https://stark-brook-37307.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Check out the response when you visit one of those img links: https://stark-brook-37307.herokuapp.com/assets/images/art_button.jpg. I don't see those files in your repo, I only see /assets/images/construction.gif, which works if I visit it: https://stark-brook-37307.herokuapp.com/assets/images/construction.gif. It looks like your repo has 2 "public" folders with different capitalization. Consolidate that and go all lowercase.

Comment: Another suggestion – use absolute paths (`/assets/` instead of `assets/`) in your `img src` attributes. That ensures your images will always load, even if you're on a sub-page like example.com/about.

Comment: Thank you Charlie !! That's really weird that it's picking up two public folders since I only have one locally.  I'm guessing that's what's going on, I'm going to try and fix it right now.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: This worked - you're a lifesaver !!! thank you so much.